# CanOpenUrl method not working ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, deep-linking

I have used CanOpenUrl method in my app, and it was working on iOS 8.4 but when I changed to simulator to 9.2, it's not working. I couldn't find the reason. These are my codes;

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"deeplinking://"]]){
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"deeplinking://"]];
}
else{
     NSLog(@"not working!");
}
```

Can anybody help me? Thank you, Halil.

Comment: docs on -canOpenURL: clearly state what needs to be done

Comment: If you down vote any answer please mention that what we did wrong.

Comment: Below each 3 answer is correct H.P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for security purpose Apple has introduced the new concept of `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `iOS 9 and above` ,it is needed

You have to add just the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to `YES` in `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary in your `info.plist` file.

For example,

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

[image]

you can see this document in [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html). for example

[image]

Comment: I added into info.plist but still not working. It's working on 8.4 but when I change simulator to 9.2, it's not. Could it be something else?

Comment: and confirm once the `deeplinking` app is available in your device or not

Comment: welcome bro , the reason you were install the new simulator thats the reason

Answer (score 3):

Add below things in your `.plist`

> App Transport Security Settings   Dictionary
>
> Allow Arbitrary Loads         Boolean     YES

Comment: Does my answer is helpful or not?

Comment: No, it's not still working bro. It's working on 8.4 but when I change 9.2, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please implement Application Transfer Protocol

add

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

in plist

Comment: @user3182143 was there really any need for the revenge downvote?

Comment: @Popeye you are java developer and you should not discourage everyone without knowing

Comment: @Popeye kindly add comment with reason

Comment: I think your mistake, I'm not the person who downvoted your answer I was challenging the person who did as it was clearly a revenge downvote. Also I am also an objective-c developer and have been for many years.

Comment: @Popeye I am really sorry, Please moderate this thing as this is developer forum not a school

Comment: @techloverr -- relax bro, how do you know popeye assigened the downvote, may be your answer need the some more information

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It is the same answer as you copied mine and added screenshot

Comment: @techloverr -- not like that bro , check my answer once bro,

Comment: I am not a enemy of you , why i do this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik added another screenshot, I got, it is better but our answer is not wrong or misinterpreting

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik So as you are moderator, you should not discourage to make it downvote

Comment: who told like your answer is worng , I dont say your answer is wrong, your answer is perfectly correct, small mistake is you were not define where need to be implement, thats all bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik then you should stop making it downvoted as they are discouraging us to answer

Comment: @techloverr No one can stop someone else from downvoting, not even moderators without banning people. You seem to have taken the downvotes personally don't they don't mean anything it is just peoples opinion that is all.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik agree sir then please punish who approved downvote

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, was not fighting for points, point is that persons are discouraging us

Comment: @techloverr For myself I have neither upvoted or downvoted. The reason being is that yes you are correct but you haven't said how to implement it and I think that's the vital piece of information, but what you have got isn't wrong so no downvote. Don't take the downvotes to personally otherwise you are going to hate this site. People downvote for the smallest of things.

Comment: @Popeye ok sir thanks, I'll mind this things from now on

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but it is not recommended to allow all arbitary loads, as it allows all non secure connection to be carried out. Instead you can allow only some specific web urls to work without ssl certificate and is the recommended way.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```